Need to use the variable globally in the test case in robot framework
I'm new to the robot framework and I'm trying to automate the API's testing using robot framework,
The framework looks as below,

I have one scenario where i need to use the variables from one test case to other test cases (both the test cases are inside the TC1_api.robot),
TC1_api.robot,
*** Settings ***
Library           RequestsLibrary
Library           Collections
Variables         ../config/variables.py
Library           JSONLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Testcase1

    code ...

    # Extract ID from response
    ${response_json}=    Convert String To Json    ${response.content}
    ${id}=    Get Value From Json    ${response_json}    message
    Log To Console    Created ID: ${id}

    Set Suite Variable    ${created_id}    ${id}

Testcase2

    code ....

    ${response}=      GET On Session    session    /api/${created_id}    headers=${headers}

Testcase3
    
    .....

Error logs,
Test Cases 
------------
[ WARN ] Keyword 'RequestsLibrary.To Json' is deprecated. Please use ${resp.json()} instead. Have a look at the improved HTML output as pretty printing replacement.
Get a single id details                                           | FAIL |
Resolving variable '${{created_id}}' failed: Evaluating expression 'created_id' failed: NameError: name 'created_id' is not defined nor importable as module
-----------
Test Cases                                                      | FAIL |
1 test, 0 passed, 1 failed

Requirement:

In one test case I'm getting the output from the response and storing in a variable and i need to use the variable in other test cases. - How to do this ?
Likewise how to use the variable in other testcase folder?

Please provide me with a suggestion and example for this

First, it definitely will not hurt if you define the variable in the suite - after all, it's with suite-level scope; the place to do that is in the "Variables" section (usually between Settings and Test Cases):
*** Variables ***
${created_id}       not_set_failure_condition    # it doesn't hurt setting some meaningful initial value, that will tip you off it hasn't been set to what you expect

Then, the way you use it makes a hard dependency on running the cases in the exact order - "Testcase1" must always be ran before "Testcase2", or any other case that may need the variable. That's never a good idea - a test case should be independent, it should verify a function of the SUT by itself.
You obviously need that ID for those cases - it has to be set so it can be used later on.
In this case I'd suggest for you to put the logic for it in a keyword by itself,
*** Keywords ***
Initialize The Objects    # obviously, a name relevant for your use case
    # the code that will get the value from where it is needed
    Set Suite Variable    ${created_id}    ${id}

, and then in your test cases you will call the keyword
*** Test Cases ***
Testcase2
    # code ....
    Initialize The Objects
    ${response}=      GET On Session    session    /api/${created_id}    headers=${headers}


Alternatively, if the value of the variable is really set only once per run - e.g. it's not changing b/n cases, you can have that keyword be called in the Suite Setup (defined in the Settings section),
*** Setttings ***
Suite Setup   Initialize The Objects

, and from there onwards - you don't have to call it in each case.
